# How can I stop the recipients email address being shown when I reply to him

Tags: microsoft-outlook

In Microsoft Outlook 365, when I reply to an email, it displays the recipient's email address after their name. How can I change it so that it only displays the name and not the email address?

Comment: Have you tried creating a contact for the individual?

Comment: That is probably the only way. Otherwise I do not think it is generally possible to hide the email address

Comment: This feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) question; is there a reason why you do not want the recipient’s email address to be visible like this?

Comment: FWIW - creating a contact has always worked for me as long as you type the contact's name in the To:, CC;, etc fields in a new msg.  However, right-clicking on the contact and choosing Created -> Email still creates the message with name followed by email...

Answer (score 0):

Based on my knowledge, there seems no option to hide the recipients' email addresses when you reply to them. Except that you put these recipients in Bcc filed.

For more details: [How to Hide Email Addresses when Sending to Multiple Recipients in Outlook 2013](https://www.howtogeek.com/185233/how-to-hide-email-addresses-when-sending-to-multiple-recipients-in-outlook-2013/)